# Type conversion in an Update query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a following query in my stored procedure.

```
UPDATE Role_Tag_Imp
SET Tag_id = 
           (SELECT Tag_id 
            FROM Tag
            WHERE Tag.Name = Role_Tag_Imp.Tag_Name)
```

Here `Tag_id` in `Role_Tag_Imp` table is of type `bigint` where as `Tag_id` in `Tag` table is of type `nvarchar`.

While running the stored procedure it gives me an error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

How do I solve this?

Comment: Well, for starters, you should find the rows in the `Tag` table that has a string that can't be converted to `BIGINT`

Comment: This query should help you: `SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Tag_Id) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later (not Management Studio since you can connect to a 2008R2 et al. DB from SSMS 2012), you can take advantage of the TRY_PARSE function as follows:

```
UPDATE Role_Tag_Imp
SET Tag_id = 
           (SELECT TRY_PARSE(Tag_id AS BIGINT)
            FROM Tag
            WHERE Tag.Name = Role_Tag_Imp.Tag_Name)
```

I believe this function will return a NULL if it can't parse/cast the value.

Documentation here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126(v=sql.110).aspx